# Throwing a bomb in LibGDX Box2D

Tags: libgdx, box2d, gravity

I am trying to create game where somenone throw a bomb . I am wondering how I can have an bomb react in a way that is represented by the following picture : [image]

Is there are any tools in Box2D that can help me achieve this?
I have already created bomb which are effected by gravity and forces. But I don't know how I need to throw the bomb?

Here how I created the bomb

```
Body bomb;
BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();

CircleShape bombBall = new CircleShape();

bdef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
fdef.restitution = 0.4f;

bigBall.setRadius(1f/PPM);
bdef.position.set(0/PPM, 10f/PPM);

fdef.shape = bombBall;
fdef.density = 0;

ball = world.createBody(bdef);
ball.createFixture(fdef);
```

And here in my render methot I apply linear Impulse

```
ball.applyLinearImpulse(.09f, 0.09f, ball.getPosition().x, ball.getPosition().y, true);
```

Comment: I guess you need to apply an impulse to the body.

Comment: Ok, but there are a lot of impulses. And how I need to use  it that bomb could react in a way that is represented by the picture. I need that my bomb go to up(y coordinates increase) and the y coordinates decrease.

Comment: I guess it is applyLinearImpulse (http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Body.html#applyLinearImpulse-float-float-float-float-boolean-), the first 2 params are the strength in each direction (a higher y-impulse will result in a higher curve) and the next 2 are the point to which you want to apply the impulse, i guess the center of mass in your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was mentioned in comments you need to apply linear inpulse to your bomb. It's pretty easy thing. You only need to make something like this

```
body.applyLinearImpulse(your_x_impulse,your_y_impulse, body.getPosition().x, body.getPosition().y, true);
```

where your_x_impulse and your_y_impulse are mass*velocity x and y accordingly.

Comment: Ok, thanks for Your answer. But look, when I apply `y_impulse` at some moment impulse need to be positive (bomb need to move by `y-axis` to UP and then impulse need to be negative, because only then bomb can fall down). Is there are  any classes in Box2D that can do what I'm asking for?(I don't find anything useful on the web except this  website http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/projected-trajectory

Comment: Impulse sets body's initial velocity. Then movement of body is maintained only by gravity.

Comment: OK, I just have updated my code, because somehow I don't get effect that I want to. EDIT robably I get it. I can't set linar impulse in render method. I need to set it in my constructor, where I create ball. Thanks!

Comment: @user3334375 you are rigth, the `render` method is not the rigth method, as it gets called many times/second, but an impulse only needs to be applied once. As nikoliazekter allready mentioned, an impulse sets the velocity of a body, which is then manipulated by the gravity (a force) over the time, causing the bomb to fly like you want it.